# Applied Theme not showing on store

Tags: magento2, theme

I have created 2 custom themes for the site, and applied one of theme as the theme store.
But my webpage/store is loading the layout of the theme which is not been applied. I have been struggling with this since 2 days, still no luck.

I have tried to modify the theme table from the db as well where I made all the types to 0. cleared caches n number if times, removed pub/static/frontend folder, Even if I delete the theme it is not loading the layout of the applied theme.

Anything which I have not tried yet?

My theme structure is below:

Theme 1:

```
root/app/design/frontend/Theme1/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout&templates
         root/app/design/frontend/Theme1/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout&templates
      root/app/design/frontend/Theme1/customtheme/Magento_Checkout/layout&templates
```

Theme 2:

```
root/app/design/frontend/Theme2/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout&templates/

root/app/design/frontend/Theme2/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout&templates/

root/app/design/frontend/Theme2/customtheme/Magento_Checkout/layout&templates
```

magento version: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide your layout theme configuration for the two themes you create and more informations about your the structure and files content.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Apply theme to store view from **Admin > Content > Design > Theme**

Then run below command

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache
```

Run setup upgrade command

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

deploy static content

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Flush cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: already tried this, but no luck